# Is kumkuma to be applied only to the forehead?

Tags: practice

Sacred ash can also be applied to the body and arms.  But kumkuma seems to be applied only to the forehead.

Comment: What is ash for Shiva devotees, Chandana for Vishnu devotees Kumkum is the same for devotees of the Mother Goddess. So, if ash and sandal paste can be smeared all over the body the same can be done with Kumkum.

Comment: @Rickross - only above the navel, since below part of body below navel is considered impure.